# Storing a large number in C

Tags: c, arrays, numbers

I have the following code where I have an array. I add a large number to that array, but when printing it, it shows a smaller, incorrect value. Why is that, and is there a way to fix this?

```
int x[10];
x[0] = 252121521121;
printf(" %i " ,  x[0]);   //prints short wrong value
```

Comment: Also note that with some compilers you may need to add an "LL" after the literal value, so that the compiler doesn't truncate it to 32 bits before you start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your number requires 38 bit. If your platform's `int` isn't that big (and there's no reason it should be), the number simply won't fit. (In fact, even the int literal should already have triggered a compiler warning, supposing that this is C or C++.)

You could always use a data type of guaranteed size, like an int64 or something like that, depending on your language and platform. Probably no need for arbitrary-precision libraries here.

In C, <s>include `<stdint.h>` and use `int64_t`, or just</s> use `long long int`, and make sure you initialize it from a long long integer literal, e.g. `252121521121LL`. (Long longs are only officially part of the most recent language standards, I might add.)

(*Edit:* `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bit, so it should be a good choice.)

Comment: what I'm actually supposed to do is read high quality 16 bit random numbers of type uint16_t (as defined in <stdint.h>) from /dev/random. When i print out the numbers before storing they are as big as 3144293114. Are these correct or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you aren't reading the numbers correctly. Post the code and we'll take a look.

Comment: int myFile = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);            
    unsigned int rand;            
    uint16_t randomNum = read(myFile, &rand, sizeof(rand)) ;
    close(myFile);

Comment: @Panashe: well, you're reading the wrong amount of bytes. You should say `sizeof(randomNum)` and not `sizeof(rand)`. (Also, `rand` is the name of a function, don't use it as a variable name!)

Comment: I changed the variable rand to randi, and all of it occurrences. But for some reason Xcode didn't complain when i forgot to change the &rand in the read() function. For that reason i missed it and didn't change it at first. Xcode compiled perfectly though. So my question is how did that happen yet the variable doesn't exit anymore ??

Comment: @Panashe: `rand` is the name of a function, so you might be taking the function pointer inadvertently (which is why I wanted you to change the name!). Make sure you have all compiler warnings enabled, as this should trigger a warning.

Answer (score 1):

An `int`, on most systems, is 32 bits.  That's enough to store a number of about 2 billion signed, or 4 billion unsigned.  To store larger numbers you need a larger form of int.  (Unfortunately, on some systems a `long int` is the same as an `int` -- good ol' standardization -- so you need to go to a `long long int`.  Better if you can find a typedef in your library such as `int64_t`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the problem with this particular number, then just use a `long long int` as suggested in previous answers.
Otherwise, for even larger numbers (`>1E19` for signed numbers), you might want to switch to a large number library or code yourself this kind of data type. You basically need to store each digit of your number in an array (or linked list) and manually code basic operations you need on them : adding, subtracting, multiplying etc.

Some libraries include 
https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/
or GMP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your number just seems to exceed the maximum value a 32bit integer can hold..